# Table - 3 cells per row

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

http://jsfiddle.net/tiitremmel/DpMB7/ - basic sample what I've done already

I'm trying to rearrange table cells so that the table will result always 3 cells per row. Table have always by default 1 cell per row.

Default table look:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

And the result should look

1 2 3
4 5 6
7

jQuery should limit 3 cells per row.

Comment: Do you want a script to dynamically convert the single-cell table rows to 3-cell table rows?

Comment: I agree with @FarligOpptreden -- its not very clear what you're trying to ask for help with here? Please edit the question to explain the problem a bit better. :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use a TABLE instead of DIVs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slice to split up your `td`'s in the fashion you want and append them to your des table.

```
while($("#source td").length > 0){
    $("#des").append($("<tr/>").append($("#source td").slice(0, 3)));
}
$("#source").remove();
```

Given this source:

```
<table id="source">
    <tr>
        <td>1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You will end up with the following:

```
<table id="des">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                4
            </td>
            <td>
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                6
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                7
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/znAj5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/DpMB7/10/

```
var table$ = $('<table class="formattedTable"/>');
$('table.myTable td').each(function(index) {
    if (index % 3 === 0) {
        table$.append('<tr/>');
    }
    table$.find('tr:last').append(this);
});
$('body').append(table$);
```

It's not the best jQuery code in the world, but hey, I'm learning :)

Comment: Thank you. this is really great alternative for my tables. I'm also learning and i was quite close to this code. Well done!